# How to pass json body through cucumber steps in C# and Cucumber

Tags: c#, cucumber, .net-6.0, specflow

I need to send the below jsons through the cucumber feature file,
So Like to know what would be the exact way I can define the json bodies under cucumber data table.
**Even I tried to define as plain jsons in the table step definition is auto-generated with multiple parameters (parameter for each attribute)**

Cucumber Scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Send a few json bodies through the feature file
Given User generate request Url
When the User uses the "<jsonBody>"
Then User able to send
Examples:
|jsonBody|
|{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}|
|[{"name":"Mark", "age":28, "car":"Nissan"}, {"name":"brayn", "age":32, "car":"Mazda"}]|
```

If I tried the above steps, and step definition gots generated like below:

```
[When(@"the User uses the ""([^""]*)""name""([^""]*)""John""([^""]*)""age""([^""]*)""car""([^""]*)""")]
        public void WhenTheUserUsesTheNameJohnagecar(string p0, string p1, string p2, string p3, string p4)
        {
            throw new PendingStepException();
        }
```

Can Someone let me know the exact way to send the jsons and how the step definition method should be? when using **.Net6.0 and SpecFlow Version:3.9.0.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using double quotes We can use a single quote in json when it passes for the step definition

```
Scenario Outline: Send a few json bodies through the feature file
Given User generate request Url
When the User uses the "<jsonBody>"
Then User able to send
Examples:
|jsonBody|
|{'name':'John', 'age':30, 'car':null}|
|[{'name':'Mark', 'age':28, 'car':'Nissan'}, {'name':'brayn', 'age':32, 'car':'Mazda'}]|
```

Then Step definition can create like below

```
[When(@"the User uses the ""([^""]*)""")]  
public void WhenTheUserUsesThe(string json)
{
    // can apply logic to convert single quotes to double quotes
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```